# Multiple locations and different user privileges for database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure what the best route to go on this is. I have a client who has 3 different locations for his business. Each locations employees can only access their locations data. The owner can access all... Then, different roles should be able to access their stuff only (finance can see finance but not sales, etc..).

What is the best way to go about this? The solutions I can think of are:

1. Create a user table, give a location ID and role ID and base the data off of that. This would require adding the location ID a lot though..
2. Create 3 separate databases and have the information display based off of a role ID. This doesn't seem ideal
3. Use functionality on the DB side, stored procedures, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofitting a [`multi-tenancy` security model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) into an existing database isn't a simple task - IMO this should be designed into the model from the start.

An extremely simple model (One Role per user, One Location per User) would look like this:

```
-- You need to add simple lookup tables for Role, Location
CREATE TABLE User
(
   UserId INT, -- PK
   RoleId INT, -- FK
   LocationId INT NULL -- FK
);
```

All sensitive tables would either directly need the `LocationId` classification, or need to be joinable to a table which has the `LocationId` classification, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable -- with location-sensitive data
(
   Col1 ... Col N,
   LocationId INT
);
```

The hard part however is to adjust all of your system's queries on the sensitive data tables such that they now enforce the Location-specific restriction. This is commonly done as an additional predicate filter which is appended to the where clause of queries done on these tables, and then joining back to the user-location table:

```
SELECT Col1 ... ColN
FROM SomeTable
   INNER JOIN User on SomeTable.LocationId = User.LocationId
WHERE -- Usual Filter Criteria
   AND ((User.UserId = @UserIdExecutingThisQuery 
         AND User.RoleId = `Finance`) -- Well, the Id for Finance
        OR User.RoleId = `Administrator`) -- Well, the Id for Admin
```

As a result of the redesign effort, as a short term solution, you might look at  at instead maintaining 3 distinct regional databases (or 3 regional schemas in the same database), and then using replication or similar to then centralize all data to a master database for the `owner` role to use.

This will give you the time to redesign your database (and app(s)) to use a multi-tenancy design. I would suggest a more comprehensive model of allowing multiple roles per user, and multiple locations per user (i.e. many-many junction tables), and not the simplistic model shown here.